# Managing dependencies in vnext

Tags: asp.net-core

At the company I work at we do the following when we need references to third party dlls in our projects:

1. Use nuget to get package
2. Pull dll's out and create a "lib" folder and add the references here
3. this lib folder is added to git so other team members have all references when they do a pull from git
4. Reference dll's  stored in lib folder in our project

We do this to have full control and know exactly what references we are using.

My question is how is this achieved when using vnext and can we continue to do it this way?

Have watched "INTRODUCING: The Future of .NET on the Server" and it seems you list all dependencies in project.json file and when you do k restore it will go and download all based on feeds in nuget config file

Comment: Storing binaries in Git is not a very good practice (search the web for articles about this). You can always create a myget feed (or just a network share) with your own custom packages if you want full control over them.

Comment: You can edit your packages.config to specify exactly what version of a dependency that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll make use of the `project.json` file. As you mentioned, you list all your dependencies in there and the *K Package Manager* will deal with resolving the missing packages for you.

You'll notice that in the json file you specify the package in somewhat of a key-value pair of `package:version`. Most examples show a version of `*` which means *get me the latest*. But there's nothing stopping you from specifying a specific version, or a specific part of a version. For instance, the [project.json file in the Autofac container of the DI project](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Autofac/project.json) specifies a specific version of Autofac:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "3.3.0",
    "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": ""
},
```

[The main DI project](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection/project.json) specifies a sort-of-specific version of `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel": "1.0.0-*"
},
```

That says *get me the most recent build of 1.0.0*

This system allows you to automatically get the latest and greatest if you want, but also specify a specific version for safety. There's no reason to copy DLL's into a custom lib folder.

EDIT: You inspired me to blog about it: http://davidzych.com/2014/08/13/specifying-package-dependency-versions-in-asp-net-vnext/

Answer (score 0):

Just noting that "-*" does not necessarily return the latest version.  It my simple testing, it always returns the lowest available version.  Per this [documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Dependency-Resolution) the calculation is more complex and returns the lowest version that "works".

EDIT: added link to documentation